# How to match and replace the end of a line?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would want to find every line that contains (boolean) and add a

```
= [ 0 : "No" 1 : "Yes" ]
```

at the end of the line.

This is for a fgd I'm making cross compatible for older Hammer versions.
I tried searching other forums and this one but i could only find a Non Notepad++ solution which i am unsure on how to use.

Example of how it should work
Before:

```
StartDisabled(boolean) : "Start Disabled?" : 0 : ""
```

After:

```
 StartDisabled(boolean) : "Start Disabled?" : 0 : "" = [ 0 : "No" 1 : "Yes" ]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this?

Comment: I looked up forums and searched throuh a cheet sheet https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html but couldnt find much on this. For now i know that $ finds the end of a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^.*\(boolean\).*$
Replace: $0 = [ 0 : "No" 1 : "Yes" ]
```

### Demo

This takes advantage of the `$0` capture groups being available, which is the entire match found.  Since you just want to append something to the end of the current line, we can just append after `$0`.